# userEvent.type inputs only last character when wrapped in act

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I found an issues in the user-event github and it says its resolved in version 12.0.1 but I'm on version 12.1.5 and I keep getting the error.

```js
import React, { Fragment } from "react";
import { render, act } from "@testing-library/react";
import userEvent from "@testing-library/user-event";
import App from "./App";

test("Gets a code and renders it in a new route", () => {
  const { getByLabelText } = render(<App />);
  act(() => {
    userEvent.type(getByLabelText("Code:"), "12345");
  });
  expect(getByLabelText("Code:")).toHaveValue("12345");
});
```

```
  ● Gets a code and renders it in a new route

    expect(element).toHaveValue(12345)

    Expected the element to have value:
      12345
    Received:
      5
```

Comment: if you're using userEvent, I think you can drop the act. Can you show us your App component code?

Comment: I did drop the userEvent and now my test pass but I keep getting the warning about wrapping user events in act. What could I do to stop that warning? About posting my App code Stack Overflow doesn't let me post the code because it says I should add more details and less code.

Comment: I'm sitting with the exact same issue right now, did you every find a solution @medicengonzo ? It seems the issue is being discussed here as well https://github.com/testing-library/user-event/issues/387

Comment: @Hylle just posted an answer which might help if you're still having the issue

Comment: Thanks @max I'll try it out at some point, although I ended up fixing it with a hacky ```userEvent.type("example", { delay: 1})```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem might be in the implementation of the change handler. I recently had a similar issue, and here's what I *thought* would work, versus what really worked. [More info at this github comment](https://github.com/testing-library/user-event/issues/387#issuecomment-819761470).

```
function handleChange(ev: FormEvent, key = "") {
  ev.preventDefault();

  // ✅ Passes
  const value = (ev.target as HTMLInputElement).value;

  setState(s => {
    // ❌ Fails (individual characters instead of progressively built up strings)
    // const value = (ev.target as HTMLInputElement).value;

    return { ...s, [key]: value };
  });
}
```